# In my neo4j db, the graphql mutation is not working as expected for 2 types

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am using neo4j dB and apollo-graphql server for my test project. I am trying to create a Q&A app where a user could create a question (with unique id) and then it would be answered by other user (similar to stackoverflow but with very minimum features).I want to create relationship between "**Questions**" node and "**Users**" node in my neo4j db via mutation.

so, in the mutations I created **User** Type and **Question** Type. But when I am trying to create relation between the user (who created question) and the question, the mutation is not working as expected.

Here is the graphql schema...

```
  type Question {
  questionID: Int! # unique id for a particular question
  title: String! # Question Title
  details: String!
  createdBy: User!
   }

 type User {
   userID: Int!
   name: String!
   email: String
   questions: [Question] # specific questions related to the user
 }

  type Mutation {
    createUser(name: String!, userID: Int!): [User]
    createQuestion(questionID: Int!, title: String!, details: String!,userID: Int!  ): Question
```

And here is the mutation snippet from resolver...

```
  Mutation: {
      createQuestion(_,params){
      let session = driver.session();
      let query = "MERGE (q:Questions {questionID:{questionID},title:
       {title},details:{details},userID:{userID}})-[:CREATED_BY]->
       (u:Users{userID:{userID}}) RETURN q;"

   return session.run(query,params)
   .then( result => {
          return result.records.map( record => {
             return record.get("q").properties
        }
       )
      }
     )
    },
   }
```

I had already inserted a dummy user with unique userID "1" in neo4j db before running this mutation query. And I ran this "**createQuestion**" mutation in graphiQL to create a question for the existing user and so I passed userID "1" as argument,

//createQuestion(questionID: Int!, title: String!, details: String!,userID: Int!  )

**And after running this mutation query, I was hoping to get a relation of [:CREATED_BY] between the existing user and the question created,** 
But my database now has 2 users with same user id "1" (i.e. one more user with same userid "1" has been inserted and the relationship is now present between this newly inserted user and question node).

What I need is to avoid to create new duplicate user with same id , and rather just to create relationship between the existing user and the question. **So could someone please let me know what I have mistaken here ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change your query:

```
 let query = "
 MERGE (u:Users{userID:{userID}})
 MERGE (q:Questions {questionID:{questionID},title:
   {title},details:{details},userID:{userID}})
 MERGE (q)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u)
    RETURN q;"
```

As you have the questionID already in place, which i'm guessing is a unique identifier I would change the query to:

```
let query = "
 MERGE (u:Users{userID:{userID}})
 MERGE (q:Questions {questionID:{questionID})
 ON CREATE SET q.title=
   {title},q.details={details}
 MERGE (q)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u)
    RETURN q;"
```

Notice I also removed userID property from question as you do not need it as you already create a relationship from User to Question

Edit:

You can solve the problem from the comment in two ways:

by adding UserID property to question:

```
let query = "
MERGE (u:Users{userID:{userID}})
MERGE (q:Questions {questionID:{questionID},userID:{userID}})
ON CREATE SET q.title= {title},q.details={details},
MERGE (q)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u)
RETURN q;"
```

Or with local merges:

```
let query = "
MERGE (u:Users{userID:{userID}})
MERGE (u)<-[:CREATED_BY]-(q:Questions {questionID:{questionID}})
ON CREATE SET q.title= {title},q.details={details},
RETURN q;"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked the way I expected. For userID = 1, the expected relationship and result was produced. But then I tried to create another question with same question id for the other user ( userID = 2 )and now in my neo4j db, same question (questionID= 1 ) has [:CREATED_BY] relationship with both user 1 and new user 2. Could you please tell what should i do in this case?

Comment: added an example

Comment: Thanks @Tomaž, I tried both ways you mentioned, but still the same QuestionID seems to be created for multiple users. And since neo4j doesnt support uniqueidentifiers so I cant create unique id either for question id, I am in deep trouble right now.Could you please help me here ?

Comment: Yes the same question ID, but not the same node, so each User has his own question ID 1... depends on your application... neo4j supports generating unique ids with apoc library

Comment: OMG! Such a quick response !! You're super cool...And i think you have a point there...I think I will settle with your answer. Lastly, could you please send a significant link for  neo4j support generating unique ids with apoc library?

Comment: check https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix and download the appropriate apoc version given your neo4j version

Comment: Thanks again @Tomaž. Really appreciable